# derivation of a differential Eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, derivatives

Look at $F(u) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\nabla \cdot (a(u)\nabla u)$.
My question is, what $F'(u)$ is. I need this for the linearization of a PDE. The idea is to use the newton-approximation. But i don't know how to handle the derivation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $F(u + \epsilon v) = F(u) + \epsilon F'(u)v + o(\epsilon)$.  You should get
$$ F'(u)v = \frac{dv}{dt} + \nabla\cdot (a(u)\nabla v) + \nabla\cdot (a'(u)v\nabla u) .$$

Comment: why is $\frac{d}{du}(\frac{du}{dt})\cdot v = \frac{dv}{dt}$? Same with $v \nabla u = \nabla v$?

Comment: Because $\frac{d}{dt}(u+\epsilon v) = \frac{du}{dt}\epsilon \frac{dv}{dt})$.  Actually the derivative of any linear map is itself.  The second term involves a product.  Its a bit like differentiating $a(x)b(x)$